# Is there any standard formula to calculate QEC's threshold with simulation results?

Tags: error-correction

Suppose I get lots of data points after simulating a quantum error-correcting code's quantum memory experiment. And I can plot the curves below(source: 10.1103/PhysRevLett.108.180501)
[image]

Is there any standard formula to calculate the threshold with these results?

Comment: where is this plot from?

Comment: Personally, I just eyeball where the lines cross to one sig fig. The threshold in that plot is ~1%. Anything more precise than that cares too much about the boring details of the noise model.